# Asp-Items in HTML Select Razor Pages. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Im trying to get an html select to populate with the code I have so far. And upon loading it keeps telling me "object reference not set to instance of an object" and highlighting the asp=items piece. Why is this happening? I have confirmed the list is indeed populated at the end of the get method, why doesnt the value make it to the page?

Screen:

```
  <div class="container">
        <h1 class="mt-4 mb-3">
            NYS Courts
            <small>Welcome</small>
        </h1>
        <hr />

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 mb-4">
                <h3>Select Organization</h3>
                <br />
                <form asp-page="SelectOrganization" method="post" name="SelectOrganizationScreen" id="SelectOrganizationForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                                               <select asp-for="CourtId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.OrganizationSelectList,"CourtId","CourtName"))" name="CourtId" id="CourtId">
                            <option class="form-control" value="">Choose a Court</option>
                        </select>


                    </div>

                    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Razor Code:

```
       public void OnGet()
        {
            //user will have the list of courts they have permission to access?
            //Hard coded for now
            var OrgValuePairs = new List<OrganizationSelectDTO>()
            {
               new OrganizationSelectDTO
               {
                   CourtID = "2",
                   CourtName = "Criminal Court"
               },
               new OrganizationSelectDTO
               {
                   CourtID = "3",
                   CourtName = "Supreme Court"
               },
               new OrganizationSelectDTO
               {
                   CourtID = "4",
                   CourtName = "Surrogate's Court"
               }
            };

            OrganizationSelectList = OrgValuePairs;
}
    public class OrganizationSelectDTO
    {
        public string CourtName { get; set; }

        public string CourtID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you pls show the whole page code and the whole model code. It is hard to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by your typo.

In your model,your property is `CourtID`,but in your view,

```
asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.OrganizationSelectList,"CourtId","CourtName"))",
```

it's `CourtId`.

You need change it to `CourtID`

```
asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.OrganizationSelectList,"CourtID","CourtName"))"
```